# Vuforia Area Target Generator ERROR Download of Matterport(TM) Space

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, matterport

Recently we bought a Pro3 from Matterport to scan a large area; however, when our team were attempting to download and generate our spaces via the Area Target Generator app, we faced a couple of issues and were unable to resolve them.

While we’ve purchased the right to download our space in Matterpak file, and our computers have plenty of space, we kept getting storage error. We also tried it on multiple high-performance Macs(M2 Max) and Windows, but were all in vain. The screenshot of the error we were getting is attached below.
[Vuforia Area Target Generator SPACE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxklC.jpg)

The MatterPak file we're trying to generate has 741 scan points with 3 active space usage, and we have purchased a Profesional plan for Matterport.

Are there any scan point limits in Vuforia Area Target Generator?
And are there any ways to resolve the error we're getting?

Comment: Please file a ticket here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/ and Engine support should get in contact with you.

Comment: You can also contact vuforia-feedback@ptc.com with a ref to this Stack Overflow post

Answer (score 2):

After a bunch of testing and feedbacks from Vuforia support team, in order to successfully generate the space, you need a steady and fast internet connection. As for the reason why we got storage error instead of connection error, we're still not sure why. But after changing to a different Internet speed environment, the problem has been resolved.